# Simple past tense and passive voice

Tags: past-tense, passive-voice, phrasal-verbs

Please help me to construct following sentence

I want to tell my friend that I got admitted in the hospital by myself i.e. without anybodys help

If I say

1) I was admitted in the hospital yesterday

2) I got admitted in the hospital yesterday

As per my knowledge both the sentences are in passive voice. Sentences give idea about some one help me to get admitted in the hospital.

I.e. I was admitted in the hospital yesterday by neighbor.

I got admitted in the hospital. with the help of neighbor.

Comment: The hospital normally admits the patient. The patient does not admit himself.  Are you trying to say that you did not require an ambulance or some other assistance to get there?

Comment: @TRomano Google search on "admitted myself in (into) the hospital". It is used a lot. Probably most often related to mental hospitals. Might not be technically correct, but the usage is.

Comment: @user3169 That a large number of people use a locution does not automatically establish it as grammatical. What if the same number or perhaps a much larger number of people consider the usage ungrammatical? In any case, it should be "into" or "to", not "in".

Comment: @TRomano Um, yes if a speech community uses something then it's automatically grammatical. It might not be grammatical in *your* speech community, but you can't say it's outright ungrammatical in English.

Comment: @curiousdannii:  Um, I think that descriptivist definition of "grammatical" could do with a little refinement, without its falling off the prescriptivist precipice.  Use of a form within a particular dialect,say, or sociolect, establishes grammaticality only within that group of speakers.

Comment: @TRomano Then you would want to say that it is ungrammatical in Standard International English or some such thing. A descriptivist should only say something is straight ungrammatical if they think it's ungrammatical in every sociolect.

Answer (score 2):

You can say:

> I admitted **myself** into the hospital yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

Passive voice usually implies another party who acts on the subject.  You cannot *be admitted* to the hospital without involving another human being (a nurse, a doctor, or at least a receptionist).  Whether somebody else helps *you* to reach the hospital and interact with whoever registers you (at the hospital), is a different matter, and neither of your sentences expresses that.

The last sentence is the only one in which "*with the help of neighbor*" serves the purpose of explaining that you had some kind of assistance.  BTW, it ought to be "***a*** *neighbor*" or "***my*** *neighbor*".